# Warping an image to the interior of a cylinder

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I'm trying to mock up some ads for the London underground, and I'm having trouble warping the image to the interior of the tube shape.

There are various guides to warping labels to cylinder exteriors etc but I cant find anything regarding warping images to the interior shape.

I want to add an ad over where the current ones are, but I'm having trouble getting the perspective to look right.

The image I intend to use for the mockups is this one:

[image]

And here's where I'm at so far:

[image]

I think I've got the skew right, I just need it to look "curved" so it looks like it's pasted to the wall. The idea is that it will be kind of experiential so the entire wall and roof of the tube will be covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Ad on top of the background tunnel layer:

[image: Layers]

Step 2: Lighten the opacity to help you see. Then do Edit > Transform > Distort on the new layer. Drag the corners to be aligned with the corners of an existing ad

[image: Distort]

Step 3: Edit > Transform > Warp on the new layer to get the nice curves. It'll require a bit of fine tuning but its not too hard.

[image: Warp]

Step 4: Increase the Opacity back up and do whatever else you need to as far as lighting and texture goes so it looks good.

Comment: Thankyou thats a much better method than what i was doing.

Answer (score 2):

[image: See Sample image]

1. Bring your image to Illustrator and create a symbol out of it.
2. Draw a simple curved shape
3. Use 3D distort to extrude the curved shape and map the symbol with your art to the right surface

You will need to adjust 3D Extrude and mapping options to get the exact result that you need.